# Failed to open EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi, 18.10

I'm using Windows 10 and I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 18.10. I used Rufus to make Sandisk Cruiser Blade 16GB (USB flash drive) bootable. When I successfully booted into Ubuntu 18.10 for the first time (Try Ubuntu without installing mode) and then clicked on Install Ubuntu icon on the Ubuntu desktop, the installation wizard appeared and did something, but somehow the setup was interrupted and my Asus Vivobook X510 UNR laptop rebooted. After that I couldn't boot into Ubuntu (not even try mode.) When I choose to boot using my bootable USB flash drive, a black screen appears with this error message:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found"
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Found
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: not found
```

I'm still able to boot my preinstalled Windows 10 Home, but I can't boot Ubuntu.

[MyLaptop Asus X510UN](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X510UN/)